# executeQueryLocally error

Tags: javascript, breeze

Latest version(s) of Breeze appear to break executeQueryLocally.  For example:

```
var query = new breeze.EntityQuery()
            .from("Items").where('id', '==', id);

return manager.executeQueryLocally(query);
```

The issue I am encountering is in the `stringEquals` call in `getPredicateFn`.

In the case of the simple query above, `trim()`is being called on id causing a

> 5 has no method 'trim'

Exception.

Here is the Breeze stringEquals function:

```
 function stringEquals(a, b, lqco) {
    if (lqco.usesSql92CompliantStringComparison) {
        a = (a || "").trim();
        b = (b || "").trim();
    }
    if (!lqco.isCaseSensitive) {
        a = (a || "").toLowerCase();
        b = (b || "").toLowerCase();
    }
    return a == b;
}
```

**Edit**

`id` is defined as `int` on the Items model and is numeric in `JavaScript`. Earlier version of Breeze did not do `stringEqual`s so there was no attempt to trim a numeric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this should be fixed. Please check v0.73.1. Breeze predicates will now perform type coercion when comparing values of different types (like strings vs numerics).